# Группировкой массива в объект по определённому ключу

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Необходимо преобразовать массив в объект таким образом, чтобы в качестве ключей были `type`.

Пример исходного массива:

```js
[{
    name: "test",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 40,
        max: 48
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 55,
        max: 61
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 46,
        max: 42
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 61,
        max: 100
      },
      {
        type: "Тяжёлый",
        min: 220,
        max: 200
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Результирующий объект:

```js
{
  "Лёгкий": [
     {
        name: "test",
        min: 40,
        max: 48
     },
     {
        name: "test2",
        min: 46,
        max: 42
     },

  ],
  "Средний": [
     {
        name: "test",
        min: 55,
        max: 61
     },
     {
        name: "test2",
        min: 61,
        max: 100
     },
  ],
  "Тяжёлый": [{
    name: "test2",
    min: 220,
    max: 200
  }]
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать:

```
const result = arrayOfObjects.reduce((acc, v) => {
        let arr = [];
        v.types.forEach(t => {
          test = {
            name: v.name,
            min: t.min,
            max: t.max,
          };

          arr.push(test);
          acc = {[t.type]: arr};
        });

        return acc;
      }, {});
```

Comment: А что **вы** пытались сделать для решения данной задачи?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko обновил вопрос

Comment: пример в вопросе не сортировка.

Comment: @Grundy А как это назвать?

Comment: @Joseph думаю, что это можно было бы назвать группировкой массива в объект по определённому ключу. К слову, если вы научитесь правильно формулировать цели, вам будет гораздо проще самому их достигать :) Удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы были на верном пути, но вам нужно лучше изучить функцию [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Решение может быть таким:

```js
const src = [{
    name: "test",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 40,
        max: 48
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 55,
        max: 61
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    types: [{
        type: "Лёгкий",
        min: 46,
        max: 42
      },
      {
        type: "Средний",
        min: 61,
        max: 100
      },
      {
        type: "Тяжёлый",
        min: 220,
        max: 200
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result = src.reduce((acc, v) => {
  v.types.forEach(t => {
    if (!acc[t.type]) {
      acc[t.type] = [];
    }

    acc[t.type].push({
      name: v.name,
      min: t.min,
      max: t.max,
    })
  })

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```